# Python: How to approach mapping a json object onto a dataframe int64 based id column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have loaded the following json object:

```json
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": true
   }
  },

  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA\"",
   "id": "2",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
    "assignable": true
   }
  },
```

I also have loaded the data frame: (ignore the second column please)

| category_id | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | g |
| 2 | f |
| 4 | d |
| 10 | b |
| 11 | c |

I need to grab the title from the json dictionary and corresponding id and create a new column in the dataframe that corresponds to the category id column. I asked this question before but slightly differnt by loading the json object into a dataframe by : json.normalize(data) and trying to map from that data frame into the one I wanted. However I ended up with a column of NaN doing that.

I was wondering can i map using the dictionary after loading it? Or is there another approach I should be taking. if this question is bad or needs to be reworded please let me know.

the final data frame should look like this:

| category_id | category_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Music |
| 4 | Dance |

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have an existing dataframe you are filling out, otherwise you can just build the id/title from the dictionary I can create below.

Assuming your input is a list.

```
data = [
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": 'true'
   }
  },
{
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA\"",
   "id": "2",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
    "assignable": 'true'
   }
  }]
  }]

# create a map of id and title to use against existing dataframe
mapp = {}
for d in data[0]['items']:
    print(d['id'])
    mapp[d['id']] = d['snippet']['title']
mapp    

#dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['1','2','3','4','5'], columns=['category_id'])

#map the title using mapp dictionary
df['category_title'] = df['category_id'].map(mapp)
```

Output

```
  category_id    category_title
0           1  Film & Animation
1           2  Autos & Vehicles
2           3               NaN
3           4               NaN
4           5               NaN
```